# How to keep updating recyclerview in the next activity by the data flow sent by BLE device in current activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am completely new to Android and just learned Object-oriented programming. My project requires me to build something on open-source code. I am really struggling with this special case. Two fragments are under activity_main, one of them is TerminalFragment. If TerminalFragment is active under activity_main, data from a BLE device will keep flowing into activity_main. Is it possible to keep passing the data to the next activity without clicking a button (in this case, menuItem(R.id.plot))? I added a recyclerview on activity_main2 and want it display the data which is flowing in activity_main.

In my testing with my current method, the recycler view won't update itself, it just captures the data in the recyclerview of activity_main with TerminalFragment once the user clicked the menuItem (id,plot). What kind of thing I need to add in my method? Should I create another Fragment instead of activity_main2? As I looked this up in the internet, it seems not possible to work that way between a fragment and next activity. Much Appreciated.

onOptionsItemSelected of TerminalFragment

```
if (id == R.id.plot){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("output",output); //output
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
```

receive() of TerminalFragment

```
private void receive(byte[] data) {
        if(hexEnabled) {
            receiveText.append("Hello" + TextUtil.toHexString(data) + '\n');
        } else {
            String msg = new String(data);
            if(newline.equals(TextUtil.newline_crlf) && msg.length() > 0) {
                // don't show CR as ^M if directly before LF
                msg = msg.replace(TextUtil.newline_crlf, TextUtil.newline_lf);
                // special handling if CR and LF come in separate fragments
                if (pendingNewline && msg.charAt(0) == '\n') {
                    Editable edt = receiveText.getEditableText();
                    if (edt != null && edt.length() > 1)
                        edt.replace(edt.length() - 2, edt.length(), "");
                }
                pendingNewline = msg.charAt(msg.length() - 1) == '\r';
            }
            receiveText.append(TextUtil.toCaretString(msg, newline.length() != 0)); //print out data
            output = receiveText.getText().toString(); // CharSequence to String
        }
    }
```

OnCreate of mainActivity2, *receiveData() is to add data to the recyclerview

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.dataflow);
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        String data;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            data = extras.getString("output");
            receiveData(data);
        }
        setAdapter();
    }
```

Comment: suggest u read up on the purpose of viewmodel in android. else u need to call set adapter first and populate the list later on.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problems is unknown how to get activity_main data onto activity_main2 dynamically , You can user " EventBus " to solve data updates dynamically , whatever you use another fragment or activity_main2 .